# C "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type struct" in thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, struct

I have two separate programs, one is being called as a thread, while the other contains a struct and main. Below is snippets of the code, and further explanation:

In my main program (we will call this main.c):

```
# include "thread.c" // my thread program
# include <pthread.h> 

struct myVariables {
    double dt;
};

void simulate(int neuronCount, double dt) {
    // declare and assign struct values
    struct myVariables *vars;
    vars = (struct myVariables*)malloc(sizeof(struct myVariables));

    vars->dt = dt;
    
    for(int i=0 ; i<neuronCount ; i++) {
        pthread_t neuron;
        pthread_create(&neuron, NULL, thread, (void*) vars);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int neuronCount = 5;
    double dt = 0.01;
    simulate(neuronCount, dt);
}
```

In my thread program, which is a separate file (we will call this thread.c):

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <pthread.h> 

// Function for thread to execute.
void* thread(void* variables) {
    
    struct myVariables *vars = (struct myVariables *) variables;

    double x = vars->dt; // ISSUE IS IN THIS LINE
    printf("x = %f\n", x);

    // extra calculations that i cut out
}
```

I have looked at many other answers and solutions for this error and I have tried following all of them. One of which was changing (void*) vars in the pthread_create() line to &vars, but the error did not change. I have made sure to copy everything exactly, but I am stumped. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your "thread.c" file has no information about how `struct myVariables` is defined. That definition only exists in your "main.c" file

Comment: Put the definition of `struct myVariables` in a header file of its own and include that from both `main.c` and `thread.c` since that definition is needed in both places.

Comment: Or, because you for some reason decided to directly include the "thread.c" file in your main file - the definition for the struct is after it is being dereferenced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the structure `myVariables` visible from the thread function.

You can do that by separating its declaration to another header file and use that, for example.

Also note that passing `.c` file to `#include` is generally considered as a bad idea because it may lead to multiple-definition error. Instead of that, you should *compile* `.c` files separately and *link* the compiled object files.

`main.c`

```c
# include <pthread.h> 
# include "struct.h"

void simulate(int neuronCount, double dt) {
    // declare and assign struct values
    struct myVariables *vars;
    vars = (struct myVariables*)malloc(sizeof(struct myVariables));

    vars->dt = dt;
    
    for(int i=0 ; i<neuronCount ; i++) {
        pthread_t neuron;
        pthread_create(&neuron, NULL, thread, (void*) vars);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int neuronCount = 5;
    double dt = 0.01;
    simulate(neuronCount, dt);
}
```

`struct.h`

```
#ifndef STRUCT_H_GUARD_8D7AA9A3_CC2D_4B76_B24D_8925426D9552
#define STRUCT_H_GUARD_8D7AA9A3_CC2D_4B76_B24D_8925426D9552

struct myVariables {
    double dt;
};

#endif
```

`thread.c`

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <pthread.h> 
# include "struct.h"

// Function for thread to execute.
void* thread(void* variables) {
    
    struct myVariables *vars = (struct myVariables *) variables;

    double x = vars->dt; // ISSUE IS IN THIS LINE
    printf("x = %f\n", x);

    // extra calculations that i cut out
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I did exactly what you showed. When I try to compile and link them, the compiler doesn't like my 'thread' call in pthread_create. Says it is undeclared (first use in this function). How would I go about navigating that? I saw others say not to include a c file at the top of the main file.

Comment: @Taylor.M You need to declare the `thread` function somewhere visible from the place where it is used in the call to `pthread_create`. The best place to do that is in a header file. The header file that declares `struct myVariables` is probably a good place to declare the `thread` function, e.g. `void *thread(void *variables);` (The parameter name can be omitted, e.g. `void *thread(void *);`, and does not need to be the same as in the function definition.)

Comment: @IanAbbott I see. I just tried doing so, and the program was able to compile and run, but the thread did not print the value i set in the struct

Comment: @Taylor.M Did it print anything at all? The process may have ended before the thread printed anything.

Comment: @IanAbbott nothing was printed, no

Comment: @Taylor.M Then you could call `pthread_exit(NULL);` at the end of the `main()` function to stop the process terminating before the other threads have exited.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235906/discussion-between-taylor-m-and-ian-abbott).